# Earth Engine memory capacity exceeded

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I want to generate time-series MODIS images of a small area (10x10km) via Google Earth Engine from 2000 to 2017. I generate the clipped image collection easily and then export each image individually to the cloud. I am using Python API as it is a very long process and should be done in batch. But after a few hours, execution is aborted and I get below message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Extract_prismV3.py", line 45, in <module>
    date = image.get('system:index').getInfo()
  File "/home/shahriar49/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ee/computedobject.py", line 95, in getInfo
    return data.getValue({'json': self.serialize()})
  File "/home/shahriar49/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 269, in getValue
    return send_('/value', params)
  File "/home/shahriar49/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 828, in send_
    raise ee_exception.EEException(json_content['error']['message'])
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Earth Engine memory capacity exceeded.
```

The area is small, and the files are also extracted one by one by two `for` loops, one for each bounding box and another for each day in the whole period. What might be the reason for such an exception? I don't believe that the code has any problem, because this exception does not occur in a determined way and it comes out to be random and not reproducable at an exact time. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Sony Vaio laptop with 4GB of ram and 64bit AMD E2-2000 processor, and my code is listed below:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
# start: 20:30 8/2/2018

import ee
ee.Initialize()

import time
start = time.time()

MODIS = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1")
Boxes = ee.FeatureCollection("users/shshheydari/thesis/AllBoxes")
boxes = Boxes.sort('boxID')

F = open("MODIS_startDates.txt", 'r')
startDates = F.read().splitlines()
endDate = '2018-01-01'

imageCol = MODIS.select('LST_Day_1km').filterDate('2000-01-01', endDate);
scale = imageCol.first().projection().nominalScale().getInfo();

allBlocks = boxes.map(lambda Bbox:
  ee.Feature(imageCol.map(lambda image:
    image.clip(Bbox).reproject('EPSG:4326', None, scale).multiply(0.02) \
    .set({'boxID': Bbox.get('boxID')})
                          )
             )
                      )
boxes2extract = range(0,168);
for i in boxes2extract:
  if startDates[i] != endDate:
    box = ee.Feature(boxes.toList(boxes.size()).get(i))
    box_id = box.get('boxID').getInfo()
    coords = box.geometry().coordinates().getInfo()
    collection =ee.ImageCollection(allBlocks.toList(allBlocks.size()).get(i)) \
    .filter(ee.Filter.gte('system:index', startDates[i]))
    n = collection.size().getInfo()
    if n > 0:
      for j in range(0, n):
        image = ee.Image(collection.toList(n).get(j))
        fname = "MODIS_"+box_id+"-"+image.get('system:index').getInfo()
        print(fname)
        Task = ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage( 
          image= image,
          description= fname,
          bucket= "modis_clips",
          fileNamePrefix= box_id+"/"+fname,
          region= coords,
          scale= scale
        )
        Task.start()
        while Task.status()['state'] != 'COMPLETED':
          pass

end = time.time()
print 'Run time was',end-start,' seconds'
```

Answer (score 8):

The error `Earth Engine memory capacity exceeded.` means that Earth Engine was unable to allocate memory while computing your request. It does **not** necessarily mean that your script inherently requires too much memory; in that case you would expect to see `User memory limit exceeded.`

If you are seeing this particular message consistently when you run a script, there might be a problem of interest to the Earth Engine team. If you would like to report it, email `earthengine@google.com` an explanation, a **Get Link** link to your script (or, if you can, a simplified version that isn't necessarily scientifically meaningful but does cause the problem), and also share any uploaded assets it requires with that address.